# Resize image (image_lib), maintain aspect ratio but scale to SMALLEST possible that EXCEEDS both width and height

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I want to take a square image and resize it to 300px * 400px (for example).

I want to maintain the aspect ratio, but so that the picture exceeds or matches both dimensions. So in the case of a square original image the resulting image will be 400px * 400px.

Does that make sense? I want this because then I will go on to crop the image to be exactly 300px * 400px.

Setting `$config['maintain_ratio'] = false;` distorts the image.

Thank you for any enlightenment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .... It will help ..

```
    if(file_exists('test.jpg'))
         unlink('test.jpg');

       $dest='test.jpg';


  $image='fg.jpg';

 $list=getimagesize($image);
 $width=$list[0];
  $height=$list[1];


   $newwidth=65;
    $newheight=95;



   $int_x=10;
 $int_y=0;




define( 'DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH', 65 );
define( 'DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT', 95 );
$source_gdim = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

$source_aspect_ratio = $width / $height;
$desired_aspect_ratio = DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH / DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT;

 // For Wide Image
if ( $source_aspect_ratio > $desired_aspect_ratio )
  {
$temp_height = DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
$temp_width = ( int ) ( DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT * $source_aspect_ratio );
  }
  // For Tall Image
else
  {
  $temp_width = DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH;
   $temp_height = ( int ) ( DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH / $source_aspect_ratio );
   }


   $temp_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor( $temp_width, $temp_height );
  imagecopyresampled($temp_gdim,$source_gdim,0, 0,0, 0,$temp_width, $temp_height,$width, $height);


 $x0 = ( $temp_width - DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH ) / 2;
  $y0 = ( $temp_height - DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT ) / 2;

  $desired_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor( DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH, DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT );
    imagecopy($desired_gdim,$temp_gdim,0, 0,$x0, $y0,DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH, DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT);


      imagejpeg( $desired_gdim,'test.jpg',100 );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Its not codeigniter specific, but I guess I can use some of your code to resize my image to specific dimensions and then crop accordingly. :) Thanks dude.